# Restrict download files from not generated Urls

Tags: htaccess, content-restriction

I use a plugin in WPMU that encrypt all downloads urls in wp-content/uploads/ : The downloads can still be accessed if users know the path to the file: e.g. www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/file.pdf . My problem is how to prevent this . i want to restrict direct downloads from not encrypted urls

I tried this in my `.htaccess` but it disable downloads also from encrypted urls:

```
Deny From All
Allow From http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/Encryptor-plugin/encrypt.php
```

Comment: To prevent browsing, just put an `index.php` file with the content `<?php // Silence is golden ?>` (or something like this) inside. As for the plugin, does it provide some GET/POST vars that you could check? Your current htaccess code does not work since A) you can't use a file (AFAIK) for a `Deny/Allow From ...` statement, B) the file is not where the request is coming from.

Comment: You can also [alter Apache's configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) to prevent directory listing.

Comment: "directory listing" is not my problem, thank you anyway.

Comment: "directory listing" was a part of your problem before you edited the question.

Comment: I fixed the question.thanks . how can enable only urls downloads generated by my plugin?

Comment: Protecting content like you are trying to do is pretty difficult. If a user can see content it can be downloaded. In fact, it already has been. I would suggest a lot of research. I don't think this is really WordPress specific though.

Comment: In what way is that URL "encrypted"?

Comment: I think he means "obfuscated".

Comment: exactly.."obfuscated" ...e.g. http://domain.com/?id-filefg544dfgd453